# finish, is finished, have finished

Tags: grammar, present-perfect, present-tense, passive-voice, when

Could you help me about this question?

I am confused about how to use "finish" with "when".

For example:

> When your class is finished, could you wait for me at the bank?
>
> When your class finishes, could you wait for me at the bank?
>
> When your class has finished, could you wait for me at the bank?

Which ones are correct? And are there any differences in meaning?

Comment: _Class_ is singular, so you should have the verb in the singular in all the examples. In your situation, you could say either _is finished_, _finishes_, or _has finished_ in colloquial English and sound perfectly natural, with no significant difference in meaning.

Comment: So, When your class is finished, When your class finishes, When your class has finished, all of them are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could you wait for me at the bank when your class finishes/is finished?

With conjunctions **if**, **when**, **as**, etc. the present simple tense should be used in the subordinate clause, and your third example uses present perfect. Though I still think it might be grammatically correct, really few people will use such a construction in their speech, and it really sounds odd.

Answer (score 0):

"When your class is finished, could you wait for me at the bank?"
"Finished" describes the state of the class.  Once the class is in the finished state, could you wait for me at the bank?

"When your class finishes, could you wait for me at the bank?"
"Finishes" is an action performed by the class.  At the point in time that the class performs the "finish" action, could you wait for me at the bank?

"When your class has finished, could you wait for me at the bank?"
"Has finished" describes a state of being that the class goes into once it has performed the "finish" action.  Once it is true that the class had previously finished, could you wait for me at the bank?

I think the binding and order of all those forms are clunky.  I'd go with, "Could you meet me at the bank after class?"